Is it possible for Thin Film Isotope Nuclear Rockets to have an Isp over a million seconds?
Thin Film Isotope Nuclear Rockets (TFINER) sound intriguing: cold nuclear rockets (with no moving parts) capable of interstellar velocity. According to https://www.nasa.gov/general/thin-film-isotope-nuclear-engine-rocket , the concept has been awarded Phase 1 funding in NASA’s NIAC.
So yes, “it is a thing”.
The article describes the deceptively simple concept: capture the momentum of radioactive decay products.

…manufacture thin sheets of a radioactive isotope and directly use the
momentum of its decay products to generate thrust. The baseline design
is a ~10-micron thick Thorium-228 radioisotope film which undergoes
alpha decay with a halflife of 1.9 years. The subsequent decay chain
cascade produces daughter products with four additional alpha
emissions that have half-lives between 300ns and 3 days. Thrust is
produced when one side of the thin film is coated with a ~50-micron
thick absorber that captures forward emissions
… 30kg of radioisotope (comparable to that launched on previous
missions) spread over ~250 m^2 of area would provide more than 150
km/sec of delta-V to a 30 kg payload.


Note that 150km/sec is almost 10x the solar escape velocity from an 1AU solar orbit Why is it easier to escape the solar system than get to Mercury or the Sun?
How would this be expressed as Isp, thrust-to-weight or other measures of rocket performance? Alpha particles from radioactive decay usually have a kinetic energy of about 5MeV and a velocity of 4% of the speed of light https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle  . If each Thorium atom (atomic mass 228) produces a cascade of 5 alpha particles (total atomic mass 6.6) … hmm
Using 4%c as the exhaust velocity and isp=v/g gives an isp of 1.2x10^6 sec. I suspect I have made a rounding error ???
Of course, only half the alpha particles are contributing to thrust through a cosine function, but since they are charged they could be focused by a charged nozzle. Even allowing for that, my isp estimate seems ridiculously high.

Very crudely estimating things, a maximum limit (assuming all of the 30kg radioactive material is used) with a mass ratio of 2 and dV = 150 km/s gives an Isp ~22,000 sec. Of course, not all the material will be used.

@Lelu ... you are correct in that only the alpha particles discharged retrograde to the travel direction are involved in thrust. That amounts to 0.7% of the mass of thorium during the first half-life.

I haven't been able to find anything further from this PI (James Bickford/Draper) or TFINER specifically, but broadening my search a bit to "thrust from nuclear decay" got me to A Nuclear Decay Micropropulsion Technology Based on Spontaneous Alpha Decay by He, Xia, Xu, Zhou, and Ouyang, DOI:10.1080/00295639.2020.1794454, which appears to be the same idea.
The portion I think is most relevant for a short answer is Table I, which I'll reproduce in part here:



Isotope
Density $\rho$ ($\text{g/cm}^3$)
Thickness of film $d$ ($\mu\text{m}$)
Initial Thrust ($\text{nN}/\text{cm}^2$)




${}^{210}\text{Po}$
9.25
10.81
32.13


${}^{228}\text{Th}$
11.72
8.53
6.12


${}^{238}\text{Pu}$
19.80
5.05
0.13


${}^{241}\text{Am}$
13.67
7.32
0.026


${}^{249}\text{Cf}$
15.10
6.62
0.035


${}^{253}\text{Es}$
13.70
~7.30
9.63



For simplicity's sake I'm going to take the quoted density as a performance-limiting density for some ideal implementation and that density applies to the whole film thickness, though it's worth noting the table title "Theoretical Areal Thrust of Typical Alpha-Decay Material with a Surface Density of 10 Mg/cm^2 [sic - the paper makes it 100% clear this means milligrams, not Megagrams]" makes its own density statement
Per that data, for TFINER's 250 $\text{m}^2$ sail area I estimate the following (Google sheet to check my work / play with numbers yourselves)



Isotope
TFINER sail area (cm^2)
areal density (g/cm^2)
Mass estimate (g)
Thrust (nN)
Thrust (g_f)
Thrust-to-weight ratio estimate




210Po
2,500,000.00
0.00999925
24998.125
80,325,000.00
0.001559633028
0.1559750009


228Th
2,500,000.00
0.00999716
24992.9
15,300,000.00
0.00003312945973
0.003313887117


238Pu
2,500,000.00
0.009999
24997.5
325,000.00
0.000006625891947
0.0006626554602


241Am
2,500,000.00
0.01000644
25016.1
65,000.00
0.000008919469929
0.0008913729487


249Cf
2,500,000.00
0.0099962
24990.5
87,500.00
0.00245412844
0.2455061364


253Es
2,500,000.00
0.010001
25002.5
24,075,000.00
0.00245412844
0.2453883052



which is all over the place, but for Thorium-228, TWR of roughly 0.003, and I think that might end up worse in a practical application if you have to include sail-deployment-mechanisms, stiffening, proposed thermoelectric layer, etc.
Table II in the paper gives specific impulses for the Polonium-210 case for varying film thicknesses of between about 70,000 and 80,000 seconds, lending some credence to Lelu's estimate of 22,000 seconds for Thorium-228 in their comment on the question.
EDIT AFTER QUESTION CHANGED:
no candidates in evidence have specific impulses within an order of magnitude of 1,000,000 seconds.

I likely made a goof in my calculations, but I used the effective exhaust velocity formula and v=0.04c. I also plugged the same value into https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/specific-impulse

You have 0.15 TWR in the line for 210Po, not 228Th, or did I miss something?

@jcaron you're absolutely right, thanks for the correction. I might've made that mistake while moving some stuff around in the spreadsheet to export it as a markdown table or just read it wrong. Embarassing. but thank you!

@Woody Table II has both total and specific impulses so I tried to figure out what the mass being expelled was by taking the ratio between the two and the results I got didn't make sense to me, especially comparing them to the "escape proportion" statistics, so now I'm worried that I got a bad reference.
